# Re-drawing canvas line in Angular based on input

Tags: angular, typescript, canvas

I have an input with two way binding that's supposed to give me a number, so that i can draw line inside a circle on my canvas, making angle of that degree with the center.

[I think two-way binding itself is working fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ev29x.png)

But it does not re-draw canvas to make the angle. App has no reaction to input. If i change the value of degrees property myself by hand, then it does work. I searched for a bit and found out about **ngOnChanges()** but that doesn't seem to work either, at least the way i'm trying to use it.

my code :

```
import { ViewChild, Component, OnInit, ElementRef } from "@angular/core";
import { CircleApp } from "./circleApp";
@Component({
  selector: "app-make-circle",
  templateUrl: "./make-circle.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./make-circle.component.css"]
})
export class MakeCircleComponent implements OnInit {
  circleApp: CircleApp = {
    degrees: 0 
  };
  @ViewChild("myCanvas") myCanvas: ElementRef;
  public context: CanvasRenderingContext2D;
  constructor() {}
  ngOnInit() {}
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.context = (this.myCanvas
      .nativeElement as HTMLCanvasElement).getContext("2d");
    this.draw();
  }

  ngOnChanges() {
    this.draw();
  }

  private draw() {
    this.context.beginPath();
    this.context.arc(150, 150, 100, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    this.context.moveTo(150, 150);
    this.context.lineTo(
      Math.cos((-this.circleApp.degrees * Math.PI) / 180) * 100 + 150,
      Math.sin((-this.circleApp.degrees * Math.PI) / 180) * 100 + 150
    );
    this.context.stroke();
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please clarify how you're changing the value? ngOnChanges is supposed to work with @Input property on component.

Comment: Inside my circleApp object, by default, degrees has value of 0. If i make that 90 by editing the code, my app reacts to it. but if i use input to set degrees to value of 90 (and i know it works because i'm displaying {{circleApp.degrees}} in my template as you can see in the linked picture. Anyway, if i use input to change it, nothing happens. no movement of the line, it stays where it is, at default 0.

Comment: It should work if you change reference in parent component